# Android room fts4 MATCH syntax AND OR

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-room, fts4

What is the proper syntax for more complex MATCH query using room and FTS4
I've found in the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) following syntaxs which I'd like to use

```
SELECT docid FROM docs WHERE docs MATCH '("sqlite database" OR "sqlite library") AND linux';
SELECT * FROM docs WHERE docs MATCH 'title:linux problems';
```

| query | result |
| --- | --- |
| `MATCH '("sqlite database" OR "sqlite library") AND linux'` | (x) |
| `MATCH '("sqlite database" OR "sqlite library") linux'` | OK |
| `MATCH 'content:("*sql*" OR "*lin*")'` | OK (partly, only last star works, will not find "mysql") |
| `MATCH 'content:sql* id:123'` | OK |
| `MATCH 'content:("*sql*" OR "*lin*") AND id:("*123*")'` | (x) |
| `MATCH 'content:("*sql*" OR "*lin*") id:("*123*")'` | (x) |

Seems like AND is not working. And I do something wrong with quotes or brackets,

Basically I'd like to get the equivalent of LIKE with AND OR and different values on different columns

Comment: It looks as though you might be hitting the subtle difference between **standard** and **enhanced** syntax see 3.1 v 3.2 in the document. Re *???* partly works, consider `The query expression used to search for a term prefix is the prefix itself with a '*' character appended to it.` from section 3

Comment: @MikeT Thanks for an answer. So I guess I will be able only use Standard Query Syntax, because there is no flag ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS.
And I wouldn't be able to change last two rows without UNION - which I don't want to use.
Regarding a section 3 I won't be able to use an equivalent of syntax from LIKE '%searchterm%' MATCH works only for prefixes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752840/ends-with-suffix-and-contains-string-search-using-match-in-sqlite-fts . I don't want to do another column with a reversed text and the result might be not accurate.

Comment: Re mysql  `OR "mysql*"` (not that I've tried).  The 'ENABLE_FTS....' are compile time options of the underlying SQLite libraries Room then uses the SQLite API, so you have no control over the compile options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the AND issue is that only the STANDARD query syntax is available not the ENHANCED query syntax.

See (ENHANCED)

- https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#_set_operations_using_the_enhanced_query_syntax,

versus (STANDARD)

- https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#set_operations_using_the_standard_query_syntax

That is that the SQLite API/Libraries, which Room utilises islikely based upon an SQLite compilation that only includes the STANDARD syntax.

The STANDARD syntax does not include the AND keyword and as such is taken to be the word itself. However AND is implied hence why `MATCH '("sqlite database" OR "sqlite library") linux'` returns the expected result.

- as per *Only the implicit version of the AND operator is supported. Specifying the string "AND" as part of a standard query syntax query is interpreted as a term query for the set of documents containing the term "and".*

In regard to *`MATCH 'content:("*sql*" OR "*lin*")'` OK (partly, only last star works, will not find "mysql")*

This because FTS is trying to MATCH a term similar to an index if it were to start with a wild character then a full scan would be required rather than say jumping to s, then sq then sql and so on.

- An analogy could be to try looking through a phone directory for a name that has an a in it as opposed to looking for a name that starts with a. The former would require looking at every single entry. The latter would only require looking at entries that start with a.

As such I believe that you could/should use:-

```
MATCH 'content:("sql*" OR "lin*" OR "mysql*")'
```