# SQLite on Ubuntu 16.04 with JSON1

Tags: sqlite, sqlite-json1

Is there a SQLite distribution for Linux/Ubuntu that is compiled with the JSON1 extension.  The instructions on the SQLite JSON1 page only explain how to load the extension after compiling it - a digression I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ubuntu Xenial comes with SQLite *3.11.0-1ubuntu1* which is compiled with JSON1 extension.

```
$ docker run --rm -it ubuntu:xenial
# apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y sqlite3
# echo "PRAGMA compile_options;" | sqlite3 | grep JSON1
ENABLE_JSON1
```

Comment: Perfect! Not only do you tell me that is available by default, you also tell me now to verify that it is.  Nice answer.