# Android SQLite query string to reach to D in A~B~C~D~E~F where A,B,C,D,E and F could have any interested length and data

Tags: android, sqlite

In an Android application,
In `SQLite` database, there is a column with the following data:
A~B~C~D~E~F
Where each of A,B,C,D,E and F could have variable length and data

For example,
A could be every possible interested name like Mike, Andy, Tom , ...
Or B could be any interested country name and so on

Now I need a Query to reach to D part, how?
FYI, `'~' character` is unique in the data (there would be just 5 characters of '~')
In other word, A,B,C,D,E,F don't contain `'~'`

Edit:
I need LIKE clause in a basic SQLite

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split a string into rows using pure SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34659643/split-a-string-into-rows-using-pure-sqlite)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32051164/2383176

Comment: @Marged,Sorry, I don't think so, I need a LIKE clause for basic SQLite to handle such an issue

Comment: Don't try to store multiple things in a single column. Each of those values should be in a row of its own in a table.

Comment: @Shawn, I tested it and understood the size of database is considerably bigger if every item is separately placed in its own column, I don't know why but it happens

Comment: The linked answer shows the concepts you need to use, have a closer look or look at what javadroid linked

Comment: No, please take a look at my own answer, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureka! It's possible with LIKE clause (NOT LIKE) in a basic SQLite:

```
          SELECT_QUERY =
                        String.format("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE %s NOT LIKE %s;",
                                Constants.TABLE_M4,
                                Constants.KEY_M4_Data,
                                "%~%~%~~%'"
                        );
```

If `D` is not empty, it is identified with the above query

Answer (score 1):

I actually don't know of a way to do this using only the basic SQLite string functions.  Therefore, I would suggest handling this from Java, after you have queried:

```
String input = "A~B~C~D~E~F";
String[] parts = input.split("~");
String target = parts.length >= 4 ? parts[3] : "";
```