# How to split string in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I have :

953-UL_CPLX_7th-CRL_PD_GPON_O as string:

```
In mysql:
SPLIT_STR('953-UL_CPLX_7th-CRL_PD_GPON_O', '-', 1)
```

So I need to split (-) to return **953** in sqlite

Comment: Do you want only the part before the 1st `-` of the string?

Comment: There is no SPLIT_STR() in MySql. Where did you see it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split a string into rows using pure SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34659643/split-a-string-into-rows-using-pure-sqlite)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it in SQLite:

```
SELECT SUBSTR('953-UL_CPLX_7th-CRL_PD_GPON_O',1, INSTR('953-UL_CPLX_7th-CRL_PD_GPON_O', '-')-1)
```

This will return any number of characters before the first "-" character.